# Prove $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k+a}\sqrt{\frac{a}{k}}<\pi$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

> $\forall a\ge 0$,Prove $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k+a}\sqrt{\frac{a}{k}}<\pi$

The book give a hint that converting the sum to the integration:$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(k+a)\sqrt{k}}<\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{(x+a)\sqrt{x}}$, so then I can use the integration. But I can't prove it.

Comment: What happened when you tried to use the hint?

Comment: $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(k+a)\sqrt{k}}\le \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{(x+a}{\sqrt{x}}+\frac{1}{1\times(x+a)}$$ $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{(x+a}{\sqrt{x}}+\frac{1}{1\times(x+a)}-\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{(x+a}{\sqrt{x}}$$
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{(x+a)}{\sqrt{x}}+[\frac{1}{1+a}-\frac{2}{\sqrt{a}}\tan^{-1}\sqrt{a^{-1}}]$$But I can not figure out the $$[\frac{1}{1+a}-\frac{2}{\sqrt{a}}\tan^{-1}\sqrt{a^{-1}}]$$ is smaller than $0$.@joriki

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a \in \mathbb R, \; a\gt 0$ and 
$$ f: [0, \infty) \rightarrow \mathbb R, \; x \mapsto \frac{1}{(x+a)\sqrt{x}}. $$
For all $k \in \mathbb N$ and $x \in [k-1,k]$, it holds, that 
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{(x+a)\sqrt{x}} \ge \frac{1}{(k+a)\sqrt{k}} = \min_{x \in [k-1,k]}{f(x)},$$
since $f$ is a decreasing function. Therefore it follows, that
$$\frac{1}{(k+a)\sqrt{k}} = \frac{1}{(k+a)\sqrt{k}}(k-(k-1)) =\min_{x \in [k-1,k]}{f(x)}(k-(k-1))\le \int_{k-1}^{k}\frac{dx}{(x+a)\sqrt{x}}$$

Then for all $n \in \mathbb N$, it holds that
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k+a}\sqrt{\frac{a}{k}}=
\sqrt{a}\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{(k+a)\sqrt{k}} (k-(k-1))
\le \sqrt{a} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \int_{k-1}^{k}\frac{dx}{(x+a)\sqrt{x}}
$$
$$
 = \sqrt{a}\int_{0}^{n}\frac{dx}{(x+a)\sqrt{x}},
$$
and 
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k+a}\sqrt{\frac{a}{k}} \le \sqrt{a}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{(x+a)\sqrt{x}}.$$
Now look at 
$$  \int \frac{dx}{(x+a)\sqrt{x}}$$
and substitute $u := \sqrt{x}$ and $v:= \frac{u}{\sqrt{a}}$ and get
$$ \int \frac{dx}{(x+a)\sqrt{x}} = 2\int \frac{du}{(u^2+a)} = \frac{2}{\sqrt{a}} \int \frac{dv}{(v^2+1)} = \frac{2}{\sqrt{a}}arctan(v)+c= \frac{2}{\sqrt{a}}arctan \biggl(\frac{u}{\sqrt{a}}\biggr)+c = \frac{2}{\sqrt{a}}arctan \biggl(\sqrt\frac{x}{a}\biggr) +c
$$
with $c \in \mathbb R$. Hence
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k+a}\sqrt{\frac{a}{k}} \le \sqrt{a}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{(x+a)\sqrt{x}} = \sqrt{a}\biggl[\frac{2}{\sqrt{a}}arctan \biggl(\sqrt\frac{x}{a}\biggr)\biggr]_{0} ^{\infty} = \sqrt{a} \frac{2}{\sqrt{a}} \frac{\pi}{2}=\pi.$$
To show the inequality to be strict, just argue that
$$\frac{1}{(k+a)\sqrt{k}} = \frac{1}{(k+a)\sqrt{k}}(k-(k-1)) =\min_{x \in [k-1,k]}{f(x)}(k-(k-1)) \lt \int_{k-1}^{k}\frac{dx}{(x+a)\sqrt{x}}$$
for $k=1$.
Now let $a=0$. Then for $k \in \mathbb N, \; k \ge 2,$ and $x \in \mathbb [k-1,k],$ it holds, that
$$ 
f(x) = \frac{1}{(x+a)\sqrt{x}} = \frac{1}{x\sqrt{x}} \ge \frac{1}{k\sqrt{k}} = \min_{x \in [k-1,k]}{f(x)},
$$
since $f$ is a decreasing function. Like for $a \gt 0$ it follows, that 
$$
\frac{1}{k\sqrt{k}} = \frac{1}{k\sqrt{k}}(k-(k-1)) =\min_{x \in [k-1,k]}{f(x)}(k-(k-1))\le \int_{k-1}^{k}\frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x}}
$$
for $k \in \mathbb N, \; k \ge 2,$ and
$$\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k\sqrt{k}} \le \int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x}},$$

Look at
$$ 
\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x}} = \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{x^{\frac{3}{2}}} = \biggl[-\frac{2}{\sqrt{x}}\biggr]_{1}^{\infty} = 2.
$$
Concluding
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k\sqrt{k}} = 1 + \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k\sqrt{k}} \le 1+ \int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x}}=1+2=3\lt \pi.
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$I = \int_0^{\infty}\frac{dx}{(x+a)\sqrt x}$$
Let $x = a\tan^2 \theta \therefore dx = 2a\tan{\theta}\sec^2\theta d\theta$
$$\therefore I = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{2a\tan{\theta}\sec^2{\theta}d\theta}{a\sec^2{\theta}\sqrt a \tan{\theta}} = \frac{2}{\sqrt a}\int_0^{\infty}d\theta = \frac{\pi}{\sqrt a}$$
Finally, $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(k+a)\sqrt k} < \int_0^{\infty}\frac{dx}{(x+a)\sqrt x}=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt a}$$
$$\therefore \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(k+a)\sqrt k} < \frac{\pi}{\sqrt a}$$

Answer (score 1):

Substitute $t=\sqrt x \implies dt = \frac{1}{2\sqrt x} dx$

The integral becomes

$$2 \int_0^{\infty} \frac{dt}{t^2 + (\sqrt a)^2}$$

$$=\frac{2}{\sqrt a}\ \left| \tan^{-1} \frac{t}{\sqrt a}\right |_0^{\infty}$$

$$= \frac{\pi}{\sqrt a} \lt \pi$$